# Iterating through two lists of two inherited classes (of the same base class)

Tags: c#

I have two lists. The types of both lists inherit from the same base type. I want to iterate through them and do operations which only use functionality of the base class without having two basically identical foreach loops one after the other.

I can't copy the lists to another list or something of the sort, as I need to use the lists in their original form separately after the operation is complete.

Is there a way to do this without writing a function?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I have two lists of inherited classes
        List<Babby1> list1 = returnBabby1();
        List<Babby2> list2 = returnBabby2();

        // I want to iterate through both, and do the same thing, which is a part
        // of the base class functionality.
        // Basically I want this to be a single foreach loop.
        foreach (Babby1 item in list1)
            item.var = 50;

        foreach (Babby2 item in list2)
            item.var = 50;

        // I have to send them as separate lists, the type being the original (inherited) class
        sendBabby1(list1);
        sendBabby2(list2);
    }

    static void sendBabby1(List<Babby1> list)
    {
    }

    static void sendBabby2(List<Babby2> list)
    {
    }

    static List<Babby1> returnBabby1()
    {
        return new List<Babby1>();
    }

    static List<Babby2> returnBabby2()
    {
        return new List<Babby2>();
    }
}

class Base
{
    public int var;
}

class Babby1 : Base
{
    public int var1;
}

class Babby2 : Base
{
    public int var2;
}
```

Comment: You have two separate lists, so you cannot enumerate them as one without creating a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
foreach (var item in list1.Concat<Base>(list2))
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

EDIT: I changed `Union` to `Concat` as I think that it's probably more appropriate.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! With Union, it takes a much longer time  (the lists are very large) and then throws an OutOfMemory exception, but Concat does the job.

Comment: `Union` will be comparing equality between each of the items in the lists, whereas `Concat` is just... well... concatenating them!

Comment: svinja, if this solved your problem please consider accepting it as the answer... this will let others know that your problem is solved, and help others to find a solution if they encounter similar issues. (it's the big tick mark next to this answer!)

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't even notice that mark, I'm new to the site. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the base class, like this:

```
List<Babby> list = new List<Base>();
list.AddRange(returnBabby1());
list.AddRange(returnBabby2());

foreach (Base item in list)
    item.var = 50;

sendBabby1(list.OfType<Babby1>().ToList());
sendBabby2(list.OfType<Babby2>().ToList());
```

(This of course assume you have the variable you set declared in the base class)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) of `IEnumerable<T>` in order to achieve this, if you plan to simply iterate the lists and not add items or perform other operations on the list:

```
static SendBaby(IEnumerable<Base> list) 
{
  ...
}
...
SendBaby(list1)
SendBaby(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, using `Count` instead. (If comparisons do consume additional CPU cycles.)

```
for(int i=0;i<baby1.Count||i<baby2.Count;i++)
{
   if(baby1.Count<i)
      baby1[i].field = 50;
   if(baby2.Count<i)
      baby2[i].field = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it pretty well :

```
        var babies1 = new List<Baby1>(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            babies1.Add(new Baby1 { Name = "Babies1 " + i, Var1 = 1});
        }

        var babies2 = new List<Baby2>(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            babies2.Add(new Baby2 { Name = "Babies2 " + i });
        }

        foreach (Baby b in babies1.Union<Baby>(babies2))
        {
            b.Var1 = 50;
        }

        foreach (var baby2 in babies2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(baby2.Var1);
        }

        foreach (var baby1 in babies1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(baby1.Var1);
        }
```